# how to open an word document on click of link button

Tags: asp.net

i have an link button in my gridview once user click that link button i need to open an a word document(the path  where the document is stored in  server would be like this c:/abc/doc/abc1.doc) so now i should all ow the user  to download  that document for  viewing it.

how to get it achived 
 thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should look at useing the TransmitFile method instead of the WriteFile method. For what you are doing, it is more [efficient](http://weblogs.asp.net/dmiyamasu/archive/2008/02/25/save-server-memory-with-response-transmitfile.aspx).

```
protected void btnPurchaseOrderOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=one.pdf");
    Response.TransmitFile(@"c:\test\one.pdf");
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hai,

Add a reference to word object library to your project. 
Then try this

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    app.Visible = true;
    object visible = true;
    object fileName = @"C:\temp\sample.doc";
    object optional = System.Type.Missing;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref optional, ref 
        optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref 
        optional, ref optional, ref optional,ref optional,ref optional,ref optional,ref optional,ref optional,ref optional);
```

If you want web browser thing just have a look at saar's answer

Answer (score 0):

asp.net, that means you want to open document in web browswer.

here is simple snippet

```
    string fPath = @"c:/abc/doc/abc1.doc";
    FileInfo myDoc = new FileInfo(fPath);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + myDoc.Name);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myDoc.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

    Response.WriteFile(myDoc.FullName);

    Response.End();
```